# opencv4nodejs saving desciptors of an image and loading back up

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am using the opencv4nodejs package and I cannot work out how to save my created descriptor information of a read image.

I am wanting to check thousands of images against each other and rather than loading each image, converting to grey scale, grabbing key points and creating descriptors from the key points. I would like to store the descriptor information in a database and then compare the descriptors on the fly.

I have saved the descriptor as a json object and then loaded the json back in and tried to create a new cv.Mat from it but I dont think the outputted json holds all the information about the image/descriptors

any help would be great, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Answering myself as I figured it out eventually.

So it appears the JSON Descriptor doesn't hold all the information required to reconstruct after saving and loading (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Instead I looped across each row and column of the descriptors. Stored the result as a JSON, read and parsed the result back then re-created the descriptor using the example provided.

```
// from array (3x3 Matrix, 3 channels)
const matData = [
  [[255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]],
  [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
  [[255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0], [255, 0, 0]]
];
const matFromArray = new cv.Mat(matData, cv.CV_8UC3);
```

If anyone would like me to go into more detail then I will be happy to help